# how to convert object into string?

Tags: string, object, jframe, tostring

I have this problem converting object into string... I make use of the `toString()` function... and since the conversion of object into string were inside the `try{}catch(exception e){}`, i keep on receiving an output error: `For input string: ""`

***What should be the problem if i keep on receiving an error message like that?***

More elaboration:

1. the **Object** came from a `jComboBox`
   which consists of items from a
   database.
2. I am using a `JFrame` Form instead of
   a Java Class.

All i want to do is to capture the selected Item from the `JComboBox` which happens to be an object.  And then after capturing it.  I'll use the value for my query in the database.

Here's my code(partial):

```
private void SUBMITActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try {
        Class.forName(Connect.DRIVER);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Connect.CONNECTION_STRING,
                Connect.USERNAME, Connect.PASSWORD);

        Object obj = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        String item_name = obj.toString();

        int month = jMonthChooser.getMonth();
        int q_box = Integer.parseInt(quantity_box_txtbox.getText());
        double unit_price_box = 0;
        int q_pc = Integer.parseInt(quantity_pc_txtbox.getText());
        double unit_price_pc = 0;
        double sub_total_box = 0;
        double sub_total_pc = 0;
        double grand_total = 0;

        //Testing
        System.out.println(jMonthChooser.getMonth());
        System.out.println(item_name);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If you have anything you don't understand regarding with the way I explain my question please tell me... i'll try my best to elaborate further.

Thanks in advance.

:)

here's the complete error:

```
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException : For input string: ""
```

Comment: Show the **whole** error message, please.

Comment: You should print out the classname of the exception as well. Try this: System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getClass().getName() + " : " + e.getMessage());

Comment: @sstendal: It's simpler just to use: `System.out.println("Error: " + e);` - that way you get the stack trace too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to start with:

- Don't catch just `Exception`; catch specific subclasses
- Don't just catch the exception; you almost certainly want to propagate it up to the caller
- Don't log just the *message* - log the whole exception, including the stack trace and exception type.

The exception looks like it's trying to *parse* a string - not trying to convert an object *to* a string. I strongly suspect that the problem is one of these lines:

```
int q_box = Integer.parseInt(quantity_box_txtbox.getText());
int q_pc = Integer.parseInt(quantity_pc_txtbox.getText());
```

My guess is that one of the textboxes is empty - so you're effectively calling `Integer.parseInt("")` which is failing.

Comment: .. thank you very much.. I am testing it without filling up the form completely ^_^ thanks again sir ^_^